# Is it ever okay to store a value twice in a database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

We're creating a (potentially) huge database which will be filled with `Users`. Each user is able to create many `Items`. An application will later fetch and list these items for the public, on their request. Each `Item` will have a 'pointer' to the `UserID` of its creator. When fetching the item, the user's name and picture(url) will **always** have to be fetched as well.

Given a possibility of hundreds of thousands of users, each with tens of items, in addition to thousands of requests for the items, I would imagine querying both Users and Items each time to be a bit much, even though it is one single query. As the Item itself will never be fetched without the users Username, is it completely unreasonable to store the Users username along within the Item?
e.g:

(Simple representation of original way)

```
Table(User):UserID, Username, UserPictureURL, Email, Address, ...
Table(Item):ItemID, ItemName, Value, UserID, ...
```

A query for an **item** here will **always** be e.g `Select * from User, Item Where..`. This will get elements from both tables.

(Simple representation of thought way)

```
Table(User):UserID, Username, UserPictureURL, Email, Address, ...
Table(Item):ItemID, ItemName, Value, UserID, Username, UserPictureURL ...
```

The query would now only require `Select * from Item`. Only elemets from one table.

Given that the User table contains hundreds of thousands of users, or even more, how much performance/speed is lost by accessing both tabes for each item-query? I know that storing values twice is **bad**, and that relation databases exist for the sole purpose of eliminating this, but if there is a notably reduced length in request-time.. is it so bad? If we were to fetch one Item, but there are 100.000 users, would it not take some additional time to query? Even when in the same query, as the first example.

I've been doing some simple math to figure it out.. If we set the max length of username to 30 chars, and pictureURL to 80, then 110 characters will potentially be 'double-stored'. Given that there are 100.000 users, each with 3 items, I.E 300,000 double-storings, this will only result in ~31,5 megabytes extra in total. That's a small price to pay for faster requests.

I realize that if we allow users to change their usernames, or when they change their profile pictures, we would have to loop through all their items and change them there as well, but I'm *still* torn. The changing of usernames/pictures can happen asynchronously, and is **significantly** less occurring than the item-requests..

I'm not sure if this is a question about opinion, or if there are any facts supporting either method.

**Edit:** I see people mentioning that *hundreds of thousands* entries aren't that much. To be rather optimistic, let's say the number *could* extend to billions. Would it change anything?

Comment: You've simplified the `Select`, but you've made inserts and updates on `Table(Item)` far more expensive as well as drastically increasing the size of your database.

Comment: Violating data normalization principles should only be done when it's really necessary to solve performance problems. So you should benchmark the applications and see if the joins are causing unacceptable delays.

Comment: @nhgrif In most databases, `SELECT` happens much more often than `UPDATE` and `INSERT`.

Comment: Db normalization is not really the same as relational theory. But what you're doing is denormalize a db for performance gain, which is done quite commonly in the real world.

Comment: What @Barmar said.  Nowadays there is so much caching everywhere - within the database itself, within frameworks (eg Hibernate,etc if you're using them), the chances are there wouldn't be extra disk accesses.  Measure first before premature optimisation.

Comment: However, as the previous comments say, profile rigorously to see if you really need it. Don't optimize prematurallt, and don't denormalize until you are absolutely out of options.

Comment: Why does a question like this get downvoted?  I think it is a perfectly reasonable question for someone who is trying to implement something in a database and doesn't have as much knowledge and experience as some people on this site.  (I could see voting to close such questions because they are to broad or asking for opinions, but that is different from a downvote.)

Comment: This question might also be more appropriate for dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Barmar . . . You can vote to close with a recommendation that it be transferred to that site.

Comment: "*hundreds of thousands of users*" is not a big table nowadays. De-normalization should only be done if you **have** a performance problem (that you can't solve otherwise), not because you **expect** one. With a relatively small table like that I would not expect one with proper hardware. Remember: relational databases are *designed* around the concept of joining tables. Just keep your model, check the execution plan of the queries and try to tune them first (e.g. by applying proper indexes). Only if everything else fails, de-normalize it.

Comment: @nhgrif I realize that, and that's exactly why I'm asking this question. As I wrote, the `Select` will be **far** more common than an `Update`. I'll go as far as saying less than 0.1% of the requests will be `Updates` and `Inserts`, the rest being `Selects`. The *drastic* increase in size is also mentioned in the question, as about 30Mb when 100.000 users, each with 3 items. The question is not how much I lose, but how much speed I gain, if any :)

Comment: Did you try it and see?  Best way to find out which horse is faster and by how much is to take them to the track and race them.

Answer (score 4):

The only way to really understand performance is to test it on your system using your data.

However, a few hundred thousand rows is not that many rows.  And, normalized systems manage to fetch data *all the time* using a simple join:

```
select ui.*
from users u join
     useritems ui
     on u.userid = ui.userid
where u.username = XXX;
```

I would expect this query to perform quite adequately for your tasks, assuming you have an index on `useritems(userid)`.  There is no need to duplicate the `username` in two tables.

There is also an advantage having an index on a numeric id (as I presume `userid` would be) versus a variable length string.  An index on an integer will be smaller.  This means that when the index is in memory, more memory is available for other queries.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is about normalized vs unnormalized databases.

In unnormalized databases (like your example with 1 table), data is being duplicated. There is really only one scenario in which this is not a problem: if you know you will never update or delete data, but only insert new data into it. If you do update or delete data in an unnormalized database you risk 'Update Anomalies'.

An unnormalized database is a bit faster and this is the reason it is used in datawarehousing. However, in the example you give, even if the tables do grow extremely large, that shouldn't be a problem at all.